# Android - AutoCompleteTextView nullpointerexception from arrayadapter getcount()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I can't work out why I keep getting a nullpointerexception when I'm using an asyntask to fetch some search results from an api and populate an arrayadapter

```
public class AddVenueActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
    private AutoCompleteTextView venue_auto_complete;
    private ArrayList<String> venues = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<SearchResult> adapter;
    private SmartImageView location_image;
    private VenueManager venueManager;
    private Venue venue;
    private Map<Integer, Object> current_venue_suggest_list = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    private TextView venue_name_textview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addvenue);

        try
        {
            venue_auto_complete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.add_venue_autocomplete);
            ArrayList<SearchResult> search_results = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SearchResult>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, search_results);
            venue_auto_complete.setThreshold(2);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            venue_auto_complete.addTextChangedListener(this);
            venue_auto_complete.setAdapter(adapter);
            venue_name_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_venue_venue_name);
            venue_name_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            venueManager = new VenueManager();

            location_image = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_venue_location_image);

            venue_auto_complete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    venue_auto_complete.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                }
            });

            venue_auto_complete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    try
                    {
                        SearchResult search_result = (SearchResult) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        Toast.makeText(AddVenueActivity.this, search_result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(venue_auto_complete.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        venue_auto_complete.setText(search_result.venue_name);
                        venue_auto_complete.dismissDropDown();
                        venue_auto_complete.setDropDownHeight(0);


//                      // go find the venue we've selected
                        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                        params.put("id", search_result.id.toString());
                        Api.get("/venue", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(JSONObject json_response) 
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    venue = venueManager.addVenueFromJSON(json_response);
                                    venue_name_textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    venue_name_textview.setText(venue.name);
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.v("Error", e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.v("EROORS", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
//      if(arg0.length() > current_query.length())
//      {
//          current_query = arg0.toString();
            search(arg0.toString());
//      }
    }

    public void search(String query)
    {
        try
        {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("q", query);
            Log.v("SEARCH", "Search query for " + query);
            Api.get("/search", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject json_response) 
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if(adapter != null){
                            adapter.clear();
                            JSONArray venue_searchs = json_response.getJSONArray("response");

                            for(int i = 0; i < venue_searchs.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject venue_search_result = venue_searchs.getJSONObject(i);
                                if(venue_search_result.getString("address") != "null")
                                {
                                    adapter.add(new SearchResult(venue_search_result.getInt("id"), venue_search_result.getString("name"), venue_search_result.getString("address")));
                                    //adapter.add(venue_search_result.getString("name") + "\n" + venue_search_result.getString("address"));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    adapter.add(new SearchResult(venue_search_result.getInt("id"), venue_search_result.getString("name"), ""));
                                    //adapter.add(venue_search_result.getString("name"));
                                }
                            }

                            venue_auto_complete.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("error", e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Log cat output

```
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:291)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:689)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:812)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.publishResults(ArrayAdapter.java:469)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-11 14:50:55.334: E/AndroidRuntime(21313):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: put your logs from log cat

Answer (score 0):

At some point your AutoCompleteTextView is trying to use the adapter before you've initialized it with its data. Hence why it's giving a nullpointer exception. Maybe you didn't retrieve the search results yet when you try to use the AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: The arrayadapter is fed a newly instantiated arraylist on the activity create method so there are no results but it should be able to call the .getCount method on the array adapter